# How to insert a set of nullable entites in Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have an Room Entity called City:

```
@Entity(tableName = "cities")
class City(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unique_city_id")
    val id: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "city_name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "city_code")
    val code: String,
)
```

And I have a list of objects of this class type:

```
data class CoffeeHouse(
    override val id: Long,
    override val latitude: Double,
    override val longitude: Double,
    override val city: City?,
    override val address: String,
)
```

I need to save both CoffeeHouse and City classes. Because there are a lot of identical cities, I map a list of coffeehouses to a set of cities to get only unique ones:

```
val cities = coffeeHouses.map { it.city?.toPersistenceType() }.toSet()
```

(`.toPersistenceType()` just maps domain type to persistence)

And then I'm inserting `coffeeHouses` and `cities` into Room Database using these DAOs:

```
@Dao
abstract class CoffeeHouseDao(val cacheDatabase: CacheDatabase) {

    private val cityDao = cacheDatabase.cityDao()

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
       abstract suspend fun insertAllCoffeeHouses(coffeeHouses: List<CoffeeHouse>)

    @Transaction
        open suspend fun insertAllCoffeeHousesInfo(
           coffeeHouses: List<CoffeeHouse>,
           cities: Set<City?>,
        ) {
           insertAllCoffeeHouses(coffeeHouses)
           cityDao.setCities(cities)
        }
}

@Dao
interface CityDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun setCities(cities: Set<City?>)
```

The problem is when I'm trying to insert Set<City?> app crashes with an exception:

```
Uncaught exception java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.coffeeapp.android.persistence.entity.City.getId()' 
on a null object reference
```

Stacktrace points on the line of cities insertion, so I don't understand how to make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have set the ID field in city as the Primary Key for that table and it cannot be null.

You can try changing your annotation to

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
```

Or if you do not want auto increment you have to make sure that the id is not null whenever you are inserting a City.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the *city: City?* and *cities: Set<City?>* in the CofeeHouse entity. Try to make them not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

To allow for inserting a with null you can use :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "cities")
class City(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unique_city_id")
    val id: Long?, //<<<<<<<< ? ADDED

    @ColumnInfo(name = "city_name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "city_code")
    val code: String,
)
```

As such **id** will be generated when it is inserted. e.g. the following (based upon for reduced for convenience).

**However**, the REPLACE conflict strategy will never result in replacement as null will generate a unique **id**.

What I believe you want is that either city name, the city code or both (together or independently) constitutes a unique entry.

As such :-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "cities",
    indices = [
        /*
            probably just one of these all three is overkill
         */
        Index(value = ["city_name"],unique = true),
        Index(value = ["city_code"], unique = true),
        Index(value = ["city_name","city_code"],unique = true)
    ]
)
class City(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unique_city_id")
    val id: Long?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "city_name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "city_code")
    val code: String,
)
```

As an example consider the following :-

```
    cityDao.setCities(setOf<City>(City(null,"Sydney","SYD1"),City(null,"New York","NY1")))
    cityDao.setCities(setOf<City>(City(null,"Sydney","SYD1"),City(null,"New York","NY1")))
```

- So an attempt is made to add the same set of cities The result is:-
  [image]

i.e. The first added Sydney and New York with id's 1 and 2, the second attempt replaced due to the conflict which deletes the originals so you end up with id's 3 and 4. Without the unique index(s) then the result would have been 4 rows with id's 1,2,3 and 4.